# Exporting html table to downloadable excel with PHP issues

Tags: php, javascript, export-to-excel

So, I'm having some issues exporting tables to excel.

It is generated but just appear the first set of headers.

I have a table like this:

```
<table>         
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5">Incoming</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center;">942367233</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">-</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">15-06-2011 08:24</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">00:00</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">Abandoned</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center;">935761500</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">1956</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">15-06-2011 09:20</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">00:00</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">Answered</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center;">942367233</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">1957</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">15-06-2011 09:21</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">02:16</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">Answered</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

And a form right over the table

```
<form action="toexcel.php" method="post" target="_blank"
        onsubmit=\'$("#datatodisplay").val($("#data").html())\'>
        <input  type="image" src="/images/icons/Floppy-48x48.png" width="12" height="12">
        <input type="hidden" id="datatodisplay" name="datatodisplay" />
        </form>
```

And then, at the PHP which it's supposed to generate the excel:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");
header("Content-Disposition: filename=ficheroExcel.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache");  
header("Expires: 0");
echo $_POST['datatodisplay'];
```

But only display the first set of headers. I've tried to remove the headers and it doesn't work neither.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the chat, I were able to solve this. It seems that escape characters weren't escaped in javascript so I've to add the following, solving the issue:

```
echo str_replace('\"','"', $_POST['datatodisplay']);;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is wrong. The HTML DTD states that a table may contain only ONE thead and one tfoot, but multiple tbody tags:

```
<!ELEMENT table
 (caption?, (col*|colgroup*), thead?, tfoot?, (tbody+|tr+))>
```

This is your main problem; the HTML is invalid.

Apart from that:

- You are telling the browser (and excel) that the HTML file is an .XLS file, which is plain wrong. Try it with .html.
- Validate the table HTML page with the W3C HTML validator and make sure it validates
- If you don't care about the layout, use a CSV file instead of a HTML file

Comment: I'm not sure what I've to do but after fixing the thead part, the problem persist. The php script is supposed to generate a .xls file. I've done this before and it worked. I don't know why isn't work now.

Comment: Yes, except for the doctype which isn't indicated.

Comment: If you save the file as .html and open it from explorer with excel, does that work?

Comment: Then your broken file name is probably the fail reason.

Comment: .xls instead of .html in your http response headers, as indicated in the original comment.

Comment: It makes no sense to try to export to XLS and instead export to .html although you are able to open it with Excel. As stated before, I've done this without this issue. Also, changing to .html that doesn't work neither. Just works if I paste the output in an html file and open with excel.

Comment: YOU DO NOT GENERATE AN XLS FILE BY SPECIFYING A DIFFERENT FILE NAME. The format stays the same, HTML. Excel is so kind and detects that it's not .xls (BIFF format) but HTML and tries to open it anyways, but apparently fails partly.

Comment: That's why I'm changing headers. To download and encode as XLS. However, as I said, it doesn't work.

Comment: You show a deep misunderstanding of fundamental concepts when working with files, their content and HTTP headers. I give up.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I don't know what's the problem. I just now that I've tried this "script" before and worked. I'm sure that my knowledge about concepts when working with files is almost null but I'm not able to understand where is the problem or how can I solve it. I've changed the extension. Removed the extension and nothing of that works.

Comment: The problem is as stated above, you're producing HTML but lying to Excel and saying "this is an Excel file, *really*", which won't work. You should return it with a mime type appropriate for HTML, or change to produce a CSV file format instead.